# Comment section on my blog disappears

Tags: blogger, comments, blogger-templates

When there are no comments in a post, you can still see the comment section, for example:  https://duonghoimanga.blogspot.com/2018/11/takane-no-ran-san-chap-14.html

However, as soon as someone comments on a post, the comment section in that post disappears, for example: https://duonghoimanga.blogspot.com/2018/09/takane-no-ran-san-chap-12.html

I am using a third party blogger template, so asking this question on the Blogger Help Forum did not help.

This is really frustrating, because even though I can still see the comments in my admin page, I cannot reply to them and other people visiting my blog cannot see them.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On other Blogger managed comment sections on other sites the comment disappears (for moderation), but not the whole comment section. Make sure you are not interfering with the [Gadget](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/165955?hl=en&ref_topic=3339243).

[This answer](https://support.google.com/blogger/forum/AAAAY7oIW-wA0TvaLn_S-Y?hl=en) is offered on the Forum:

> Expert - Top Contributor (Alumni)
>   Yoboy - Blogger Top Contributor
>
> > Edit your post (any one of them) - on your right, click on 'Options' - What does it say under 'Reader Comments'?
> >
> > Also, make sure the comment box under 'Dashboard - Layout - Blog Posts - Edit' is checked...
> >
> > Another thing to make sure is your settings. Go to Dashboard - Settings - Posts and Comments - Comment location - Embedded.
> >
> > If you think all these settings are right, and you still aren't seeing your comment link/form, try resetting your template. First, make a backup by going to Dashboard - Template - Backup/restore - Download Full Template. Next, go to Dashboard - Template - Edit HTML - Proceed - Revert Widget Templates to Default.

A **[second answer](https://support.google.com/blogger/forum/AAAAY7oIW-wSTgUKBex6gE?hl=en)** is offered for Disqus users.

It's difficult to read the source ([Firefox or Chrome](http://view-source:https://duonghoimanga.blogspot.com/2018/09/takane-no-ran-san-chap-12.html)) due to the packing function see: eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r) but you can see that the comments section is visible in the source of the second link above.

When I view the source I can see: "   'disableGComments': true " - search for that text in the page source view. Please note that [comments from Google](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2019/01/an-update-on-google-and-blogger.html) are no longer supported. Check that your (unnamed) 3rd party template has been updated; perhaps the 3rd party script is interacting with the website and its seperate commenting mechanism.

You can [manage your comments](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/187141?hl=en&ref_topic=3339243) and approve them if necessary.

> **[Moderate comments](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/187141?hl=en&ref_topic=3339243)**
>   **Turn on comment moderation to review comments before publishing.**
>
> **Only administrators can moderate comments.**
>
> > Sign in to Blogger.
> >      1. In the top left, click the Down Arrow. ⬇
> >      2. Select the blog to update.
> >      3. In the left menu, click **Settings** and then **Posts, comments and sharing**.
> >      4. Next to "Comment Moderation," select how often you want to review comments before they're published.
> >      5. In the top right, click **Save settings**.
>
> **Approve or delete a comment**
>
> > Sign in to Blogger.
> >     1. In the top left, click the Down Arrow. ⬇
> >     2. Select the blog to update.
> >     3. In the left menu, click **Comments** and then **Awaiting moderation**.
> >     4. Read the comment and **Publish**, **Delete**, or **Spam**.
>
> **Publish or reject comments from your email**
>
> > If you enter an email address to manage comments, you will get an email when you get a new comment.
> >
> > In the email, click **Publish**, **Delete**, or **Reject**.
> >     If you reject a comment, it will be deleted.

If there's an error in the scripts unapproved comments can block that section.